# I want to make a Pause/settings screen

Tags: java, pause

I've been working on a game for awhile now. I've encountered an issue that I can't seem to resolve.

I've written it such that when I press the letter "Q", the pause menu comes up. But my game doesn't freeze. I've tried the Thread.sleep(); method but the entire game freezes.

**Game Code**

```
package flappyBird;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;             // for Random function
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class FlappyBird extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener, KeyListener
{   


    GUI guis = new GUI();

    Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 1, 65);

    public static FlappyBird flappyBird;

    public final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 800;

    public Renderer renderer;

    public Rectangle bird;

    public ArrayList<Rectangle> columns;

    public int ticks, yMotion, score;

    public boolean gameOver, started;

    public Random rand;

    public FlappyBird()
    {
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);

        renderer = new Renderer();
        rand = new Random();

        jframe.add(renderer);
        jframe.setTitle("Flappy Block");
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        jframe.addMouseListener(this);
        jframe.addKeyListener(this);
        jframe.setResizable(false);
        jframe.setVisible(true);

        bird = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 2 - 10, HEIGHT / 2 - 10, 20, 20);
        columns = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

        addColumn(true);
        addColumn(true);
        addColumn(true);
        addColumn(true);

        timer.start();
    }

    public void addColumn(boolean start)
    {
        int space = 300;
        int width = 100;
        int height = 50 + rand.nextInt(300);

        if (start)
        {
            columns.add(new Rectangle(WIDTH + width + columns.size() * 300, HEIGHT - height - 120, width, height));
            columns.add(new Rectangle(WIDTH + width + (columns.size() - 1) * 300, 0, width, HEIGHT - height - space));
        }
        else
        {
            columns.add(new Rectangle(columns.get(columns.size() - 1).x + 600, HEIGHT - height - 120, width, height));
            columns.add(new Rectangle(columns.get(columns.size() - 1).x, 0, width, HEIGHT - height - space));
        }
    }

    public void paintColumn(Graphics g, Rectangle column)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.green.darker());
        g.fillRect(column.x, column.y, column.width, column.height);
    }

    public void jump()
    {



        if (gameOver)
        {
            bird = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 2 - 10, HEIGHT / 2 - 10, 20, 20);
            columns.clear();
            yMotion = 0;
            score = 0;

            addColumn(true);
            addColumn(true);
            addColumn(true);
            addColumn(true);

            gameOver = false;
        }

        if (!started)
        {
            started = true;
        }
        else if (!gameOver)
        {
            if (yMotion > 0)
            {
                yMotion = 0;
            }

            yMotion -= 13;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        int speed = 10;

        ticks++;


              if (started)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++)
            {
                Rectangle column = columns.get(i);

                column.x -= speed;
            }

            if (ticks % 2 == 0 && yMotion < 15)
            {
                yMotion += 2;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++)
            {
                Rectangle column = columns.get(i);

                if (column.x + column.width < 0)
                {
                    columns.remove(column);

                    if (column.y == 0)
                    {
                        addColumn(false);
                    }
                }
            }

            bird.y += yMotion;

            for (Rectangle column : columns)
            {
                if (column.y == 0 && bird.x + bird.width / 2 > column.x + column.width / 2 - 10 && bird.x + bird.width / 2 < column.x + column.width / 2 + 10)
                {
                    score++;
                }

                if (column.intersects(bird))
                {
                    gameOver = true;

                    if (bird.x <= column.x)
                    {
                        bird.x = column.x - bird.width;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (column.y != 0)
                        {
                            bird.y = column.y - bird.height;
                        }
                        else if (bird.y < column.height)
                        {
                            bird.y = column.height;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (bird.y > HEIGHT - 120 || bird.y < 0)
            {
                gameOver = true;
            }

            if (bird.y + yMotion >= HEIGHT - 120)
            {
                bird.y = HEIGHT - 120 - bird.height;
                gameOver = true;
            }

        }


        renderer.repaint();
    }

    public void repaint(Graphics g)
    {

        g.setColor(Color.cyan);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillRect(0, HEIGHT - 120, WIDTH, 120);

        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(0, HEIGHT - 120, WIDTH, 20);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(bird.x, bird.y, bird.width, bird.height);

        for (Rectangle column : columns)
        {
            paintColumn(g, column);
        }

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 100));

        if (!started)
        {
            g.drawString("Click to start!", 75, HEIGHT / 2 - 50);

        }

        if (gameOver)
        {
            g.setFont(myFont);
            g.drawString("Final Score:", 5, HEIGHT / 5 - 65);
            g.drawString("Game Over!", 200, HEIGHT / 2 - 70);
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(score),  WIDTH / 2 - 25, 100);
            ;
        }

        if (!gameOver && started)
        {
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(score), WIDTH / 2 - 25, 100);
        }
    }

    public void DrawMenu(Graphics g)
    {
        guis.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        flappyBird = new FlappyBird();


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        jump();
    }


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
          int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

          if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
              jump();
          if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)              

                  guis.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

        @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }
}
```

**Pause Menu Code**

```
package flappyBird;

import java.awt.EventQueue;    
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;

public class GUI {      

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public void guis() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI window = new GUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public GUI() {
        initialize();           

            JFrame jframe = new JFrame();

            jframe.setTitle("Pause Menu");
            jframe.setResizable(false);



    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */


    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        JButton btnContinue = new JButton("Continue");
        btnContinue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


                frame.dispose();
            }

        });
        btnContinue.setBounds(146, 67, 113, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnContinue);

        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit Game");
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure?", "Exit",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                  System.exit(0);
                } else {

                }
            }




        });
        btnExit.setBounds(146, 181, 113, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnExit);

        JButton btnShare = new JButton("Share");
        btnShare.setBounds(10, 101, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnShare);

        JButton btnSaveHighscore = new JButton("Save High Score ");
        btnSaveHighscore.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            }
        });
        btnSaveHighscore.setBounds(137, 135, 132, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnSaveHighscore);

        JButton btnLoadHighScore = new JButton("Load High Score");
        btnLoadHighScore.setBounds(137, 101, 132, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnLoadHighScore);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Cheat Codes");
        btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Press A A A B for 100 points instant.");

            }
             });
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {



            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(294, 101, 105, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
    }
    private static void addPopup(Component component, final JPopupMenu popup) {
        component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    showMenu(e);
                }
            }
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    showMenu(e);
                }
            }
            private void showMenu(MouseEvent e) {
                popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        });
    }


    public void setVisible(boolean b){

        guis();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to introduce a new boolean variable called "paused" or anything like this.

When you enter the menu, you have to set it to true, and after exiting the menu, you set it to false. I couldn't really find your code for this though.

In your actionPerformed you will have to check the paused-flag, and if it's set not increment the time / not repaint etc.

So it's basically

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(!paused)
    ...
}
```

and somewhere else:

```
"when q-key pressed"
{
    paused = !paused; // toggle the Pause
    if(paused) DrawPauseMenu();
}
```

Comment: Do my gui work then if i do it that way? Just boot up eclipse and try my code first. Since i can get a pause menu to work. But i want it to be like if i press Q the game freezes, but i can use the GUI

Comment: You have to make sure what you "exclude" in your execution when, paused is set.
You must not ignore all events. Only ignore Jump-Events, or Timer Updates, so don't let the bird move.

Comment: Oh ok, but i've tryed what u wrote. I nothing happends. The only thing change i did to your code was  'if (paused) guis.setVisible(True);

so now it does the same as before, shows the gui but dont freezes the game  :/ I am new to coding tho

Comment: Hey, KillPinguin. Do have any answears for this?

Comment: @AndreasWefring the thing is that your code is very unstructured and I didn't spend too much time trying to understand it tbh.
Thus I did not write an extensive answer.

What you need to do is introduce a Pause-State (via the variable) and while in Pause-State wrap all Statements that would update the game with `if(!paused) { ... }`
You still have to listen to important events though. So don't filter out anything while paused, just updates to the bird, and still notice clicks on the UI and stuff...

Comment: Hey! I dont know why, but today it worked. Thanks alot!!